# load extensions after google search page is loaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i want to load my chrome extensions after the google search page is completely loaded. May i know the events of google search page occuring after we search something on it?

Answer (score 1):

please see this : http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

And more specifically the section :

run_at
string
Optional.

Controls when the files in js are injected. Can be "document_start", "document_end", or "document_idle". Defaults to "document_idle". Instead of waiting for a js/browser event, I would just run_at document_idle or document_end. This works for me.

T.